# Retry Mechanism in Appium Android Automation using Java

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

everyone! I'm a newbie in Android Automation using Java and Appium. I just wanted to ask and gather some more information on how do you implement retry mechanism in your codes? As I read that this mechanism is very reliable not just in Android but automation in general.

I'm planning to implement the try/catch method as retry mechanism, however, I think using this method to every softAsserts and actions is not the best practice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.